# Unable to load sqlceme35.dll when using vsdbcmd.exe

Tags: sql-server-2008, vsdbcmd

I'm using vsdbcmd.exe to deploy a database to SQL Server 2008 on Windows 7 x64 and I'm getting an error message saying:

> An unexpected failure occuured: Unable to load DLL 'sqlceme35.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

I'm not sure why this message appears. The deploy script has nothing to do with SQL CE and the deployment works on other Windows 7 x64 machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's annoying there's no fully standalone way of running vsdbcmd, it relies on various things to import / generate scripts. Depending on the machine you're running it on, you may need to install SQL CE (amongst other things).

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bahill/archive/2009/02/21/deploying-your-database-project-without-vstsdb-installed.aspx#comments) is the clearest list of dependencies I've found (although a little out of date, as I believe the registry entry is no longer required)

This [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193258.aspx) article describes in more detail the "special requirements" for 64bit systems.

Hope this helps,

Matt